# Limit of a complex number raised to a power

Tags: complex-numbers

This question has been asked and answered here:[limit when it exists of a complex number raised to an integral power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72890/what-is-the-limit-when-it-exists-of-a-complex-number-raised-to-an-integral-pow) but I don't understand why this is so and I can't comment on the original question.

Can someone explain this to me?

my specific problem is finding
$$
\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} c_n
$$
with
$$
c_n= \left(\frac 14\sqrt 2+\frac 14\sqrt 2i\right)^n
$$

I see that $$c_n=  \left(\frac 14\sqrt 2+\frac 14\sqrt 2i\right)^n = \left(\frac 12\left(\cos\left(\frac \pi 4\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right)\right)^n
$$

but not why 
$$
\lvert c_n\rvert=
\left(\frac 12\left\lvert \cos\left(\frac \pi 4\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right\rvert\right)^n=\left(\frac12\right)^n$$

I feel like I could probably answer a question on a test but I don't understand why it's like this

Cheers
Andy

Comment: Hint: $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$

Comment: When you multiply complex numbers together, you can multiply their magnitudes and add their moduli. So, you're right that the magnitude of $C_n$ is $(\frac{1}{2})^n$. However, I'm not sure what you did with the middle step there.

Comment: The expression $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ is a point on the unit circle. Knowing that you can conclude that it has a magnitude of 1.

Comment: @kaynex that was taken from the solution. I'm studying in German so I'm not sure what the moduli are but I'll look it up